# Assigning attribute of environment object from within function by reference

Tags: r, attributes, assign

Here is a simplified example:

```
e <- new.env()
e$var <- 'some.val'
attr(e$var, 'attrib') <- 'some.attrib' 
attr(e$var, 'attrib')
#[1] "some.attrib"

assign_new_attrib <- function(obj) {
   attr(obj, 'attrib') <<- 'some.new.attrib'
}

assign_new_attrib(e$var)
#Error in attr(obj, "attrib") <<- "some.new.attrib" : 
#  object 'obj' not found
attr(e$var, 'attrib')
#[1] "some.attrib"
```

I have a variable `var` in environment `e` which has an attribute `attrib`. Now I have a function `assign_new_attrib` which takes a object and assigns it a new attribute `attrib`. As you can see, the above code results in a error "object 'obj' not found" due to the fact that `<<-` can not resolve the variable from within the function.

How can I define function `assign_new_attrib()` to assign the new attribute by referece?

Comment: Use <- rather than <<-

Comment: If its not clear: the final result of `attr(e$var, 'attrib')` should be `'some.new.attrib'`.

Comment: See the `setattr` function from `data.table`, if you want to change attributes by reference. Try `assign_new_attrib_DT <- function(obj) data.table::setattr(obj, 'attrib', 'some.new.attrib')`.

Comment: @nicola, that is a good answer. Don't know why you put it as a comment. I would definitely accept it! `data.table` is a very common package, and `data.table::setattr()` works on any object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [comments by nicola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477480/assigning-attribute-of-environment-object-from-within-function-by-reference#comment81910107_47477480):

See the `setattr` function from `data.table`, if you want to change attributes by reference. Try:

```
assign_new_attrib_DT <- function(obj) data.table::setattr(obj, 'attrib', 'some.new.attrib')
```